# If a C program crashes, will a MySQL connection be closed automatically?

Tags: mysql, c

Will MySQL connections be automatically closed if my C program crashes?

Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with C and I'm debugging some code that someone else wrote. I'm trying to diagnose a problem that is causing my MySQL server connections to be maxed out. There are lots of programs running and it could've been caused by any but I believe I've narrowed it down to a particular one.

I have reason to believe that something caused the program to crash, and then it was restarted by [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). This may have happened upwards of 20 times in a row because supervisor attempts to restart the program after a crash. This is all fine, I can likely find the problem myself.

Now I can't seem to find any information on whether C programs will clean up MySQL connections after dying.

We start the program with a standard connection process.

```
MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
if (con == NULL)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    exit(1);
    }

if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "username", "password", "database", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
    {
    finish_with_error(con);
    }
```

For the record, `finish_with_error()` is

```
void finish_with_error(MYSQL *con)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    mysql_close(con);
    exit(1);
    }
```

Anyway, the script runs as intended usually and ends with

`mysql_close(con);`

So my question is, if the program crashes at some point between opening the connection and closing it, will the connection be automatically closed or will it stay open indefinitely?

Comment: It depends on the system running your program how it will reclaim resources on shutdown, and what this means for open connections. Worst case they might continue to take up resources on the mysql-side until a timeout occurs. If your `finish_with_error`-handler runs, the connection is closed correctly. But if a program "crashes" by some other way (e.g. being killed from the OS, Segfault,...) this will not be called.

Comment: @Hulk Yeah that's what I was thinking. So the connection should timeout eventually. I've just looked it up and it seems that the timeout is 8 hours. I wasn't sure how this was handled but I think it's very likely that my system is not cleaning up the connections when it shuts down unexpectedly.